# findBy() foreignKey is not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

There is a relationship between the rubric and brand table (Many rubric to One brand).

Here is my code

```
    $dbChoices = $this->getConfigurationPool()
        ->getContainer()
        ->get('Doctrine')
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('RibambelMainBundle:RubricMenu')
        ->findBy(array('brand_id' => 2));
```

Everytime this part is run, I got the following error:

> Unrecognized field: brand_id

The brand_id column is found in the rubric table.
[image]

Anyone who can help me with this or show me another way of doing it?

```
class RubricMenu
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $brand;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return RubricMenu
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set position
     *
     * @param integer $position
     *
     * @return RubricMenu
     */
    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get position
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }


    /**
     * Set brand
     *
     * @param \Ribambel\MainBundle\Entity\Brand $brand
     *
     * @return RubricMenu
     */
    public function setBrand(\Ribambel\MainBundle\Entity\Brand $brand = null)
    {
        $this->brand = $brand;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get brand
     *
     * @return \Ribambel\MainBundle\Entity\Brand
     */
    public function getBrand()
    {
        return $this->brand;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the entity class for your RubricMenu.I think you have to search the repo by the property you set in there .

Comment: I have updated the question with the RubricMenu entity. @l.g.karolos You can have a look.

Comment: Try ->findBy(array('brand' => 2));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching by a foreign key simply does not make sense from an object point of view. `brand_id` is not a field of your `RubricMenu` entity, `brand` is.

If you have a `Brand` entity, then you can use `findBy` (or the magic method `findByBrand`) like this: (with `$myBrand` an instance of `Brand`)

```
$repository->findBy(['brand' => $myBrand]);
// OR
$repository->findByBrand($myBrand);
```

If you simply have the id of your target entity, you can use the `IDENTITY` DQL function but in that case you cannot use `findBy` directly as it expects a valid field name. Thus, you will need to add a method in your `RubricMenu` repository. Your method could look like this:

```
public function findByBrandId($brandId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('rm');
    $qb->where('IDENTITY(rm.brand) = :brandId')
       ->setParameter('brandId', $brandId);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

---

On a side note, as pointed out by @l.g.karolos's answer, doing

```
$repository->findBy(['brand' => $brandId]);
// OR
$repository->findByBrand($brandId);
```

will also work as the `findBy` method internals will be able to resolve that the given parameter is an ID of a `Brand` entity, thus it will produce the same query as if you had given the corresponding `Brand` instance.

Comment: It works.

I needed the data in the position field which has the same foreign key. That is why I was trying to do the search using the foreign key.

Thank you.

Comment: findByBrandId is the default doctrine function and should work with both integer id value and entity object value.

Comment: No, calling `findByBrandId` will trigger the following error: `Entity 'RubricMenu' has no field 'brandId'`. That being said, it is true that you can use the magic method `findByBrand`. I added it to my post.

Comment: @Alan T. you can use findBy method with all fields on your table. findByBrand if you have field named Brand.

Answer (score 6):

Based on your entity you should do the following.

```
$dbChoices = $this->getConfigurationPool()
        ->getContainer()
        ->get('Doctrine')
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('RibambelMainBundle:RubricMenu')
        ->findBy(array('brand' => 2));
```

Comment: It works. 
@Alan T. answer is closer to what I was searching for. I'' go with that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i thing you can do:

```
$dbChoices = $this->getConfigurationPool()
        ->getContainer()
        ->get('Doctrine')
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('RibambelMainBundle:RubricMenu')
        ->findBy(array('brand' => $brand));
```

if you have `$brand` object (`...\Entity\Brand`)

---

Example on https://www.wanadev.fr/56-comment-realiser-de-belles-requetes-sql-avec-doctrine/ :

```
$user = …;
$category = …;

$em = $this->container->get("doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager");
$entities = $em->getRepository(MyClass::class)->findBy([
    "user" => $user,
    "category" => $category,
]);
```